# Calculating robust standard errors for lme multi-level model

Tags: regression, nlme, multilevel-analysis

I ran a multi-level model using the nlme R package. Testing the assumptions of the model, I found that there's heteroscedasticity among the residuals. Therefore, I tried calculating robust standard errors using the Sandwich package but R only returns one these of two errors (interchangeable between the codes; I can't figure out a systematic behind this). I also tried the same code on a model I created using lme4 but the errors are the same:

```
meatHC(random_slopes, type = HC2, omega = NULL)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'DV' not found
```

```
coeftest(random_slopes, vcov = vcovHC(random_slopes, type = 'HC2'))
Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
  no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "lme"``
```

This is my model:

```
random_slopes <- lme(DV ~ A_Dummy + B_Dummy + C_mean_centered + D_mean_centered + 
E_mean_centered +
                      F_mean_centered, data=data, 
                      random= ~ A_Dummy + B_Dummy + C_mean_centered |ID,
                      method="ML",
                      na.action = na.omit, 
                      control = lmeControl(msMaxIter = 1000000, msMaxEval = 1000000), 
                      correlation = corRatio(form = ~ A_Dummy + B_Dummy |ID))
summary(random_slopes)
```

As a beginner in R, is there a way for me to solve these issues and calculate robust standard errors?

Any help would be highly appreciated!